# Drawing multiple-multicolumn table in latex

Tags: tables

I have a problem for drawing a multicolumn table in latex.

This is what I want to draw:
[image]

Can anyone help with it?

The colour of the text and symbol doesn't matter. I want to know is how to draw this table. If the text colour also includes, I would be glad that.

This is what I am trying currently.

```
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{XSS} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{CSRF} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{SQLi} &
        \multicolumn{2}{*}{POST} & GET \\
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{BufferOverflow}\\
    & StorePayloads & Sanitize(Invalid) & Successful & Anti-CSRF token & NOT & StorePAyloads & NOT & ReturnData & StorePayloads & InvalidToStore & Successful\\
    \hline
    Camera2 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Camera1 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    Cam & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
    IoT & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: I just draw above table with Microsoft Word. I do searching and found this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166263/drawing-multicolumn-table-in-latex?newreg=19d8d6e09eee4800a6beb9e5826d0443). But the table that I wanted is more complicated. There is also the error that table cannot be fixed on the page.

Comment: You can have in landscape orientation.

Comment: The `*` in `\multicolumn{2}{*}{POST}` is wrong. You probably wanted something like `\multicolumn{2}{c}{POST} `

Comment: Also, there is either a column specifier missing or a `&` too much in every line of the table.

Comment: & is too much in every line because I skipped for the symbols as blanks.

Comment: @Yan: I get, that there are many `&`s because the cells have no contents. However, `Camera2 & & & & & & & & & & & & \\ ` equals 13 columns while you only specified 12 (`\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose this variant layout, where only the main body of the table has vertical lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table, svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{bbding}
\def\cmb{\CheckmarkBold}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}
\setcellgapes{4pt}\makegapedcells
  \begin{tabular}{!{\vline width 0.8pt}l!{\vline width 0.8pt}*{2}{ >{\color{LimeGreen}}c|}>{\color{red}}c!{\vline width 0.8pt} *{3}{>{\color{red}}c!{\vline width 0.8pt}c|}c|>{\color{red}}c!{\vline width 0.8pt}}
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{SQLi}} \\[-0.5ex]
     \cmidrule(lr){6-9}\addlinespace[-0.5ex]
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{XSS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CSRF} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{POST}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{GET}} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{BufferOverflow} \\[-1.5ex]
      \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-12}\addlinespace[-1.5ex]
  \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{Store\\ Payloads}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ \thead{Sanitize\\ (Invalid)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\color{red}Successful} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\color{red}}c}{\thead{Anti-CSRF\\ token}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{NOT}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\color{red}}c}{\thead{Store\\ Payloads}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{NOT}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\color{red}}c}{\thead{Return\\ Data}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ \thead{Store\\ Payloads}} &\multicolumn{1}{c}{ \thead{Invalid\\ to store}} & \multicolumn{1}{>{\color{red}}c}{\thead{Successful}}\\[-0.5ex]
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
    Camera2 & \cmb & \cmb & & \ding{55} & & \cmb & & & & & \\
\hline
    Camera1 &\cmb & \cmb & \cmb & \ding{55} & & \cmb & & & & &\cmb \\
\hline
    Cam & \cmb & \cmb & \cmb & \ding{55} & & \cmb & & & & & \cmb \\
\hline
    IoT & \cmb & & \cmb & \ding{55} & & & & \cmb & & & \cmb \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here are two different versions of your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
    \hline
     &
      \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\thead{XSS}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\thead{CSRF}} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\thead{SQLi}} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\thead{BufferOverflow}}\\ \cline{6-9}
      & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{ } &
      \multicolumn{1}{c|}{ } &  \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{POST}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{GET}} &\multicolumn{3}{c|}{ }\\ \hline
    & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{Sanitize\\ (Invalid)} & \thead{Successful} & \thead{Anti-CSRF\\ token} & \thead{NOT} & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{NOT} & \thead{Return\\ Data} & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{Invalid\\ to store} & \thead{Successful}\\
    \hline
    Camera2 & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \hline
    Camera1 & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \hline
    Cam & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \hline
    IoT & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
  \begin{tabular}{*{12}{l}}
     &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{XSS}} &
      \multicolumn{1}{c}{\thead{CSRF}} &
      \multicolumn{4}{c}{\thead{SQLi}} &
      \multicolumn{3}{c}{\thead{BufferOverflow}}\\ \cline{6-9}
      & & & & &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{POST}}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{GET}} & \\ 
      \cmidrule(r){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(lr){8-9} \cmidrule(l){10-12}
    & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{Sanitize\\ (Invalid)} & \thead{Successful} & \thead{Anti-CSRF\\ token} & \thead{NOT} & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{NOT} & \thead{Return\\ Data} & \thead{Store\\ Payloads} & \thead{Invalid\\ to store} & \thead{Successful}\\
    \midrule
    Camera2 & & & & & & & & & & &  \\

    Camera1 & & & & & & & & & & &  \\

    Cam & & & & & & & & & & &  \\

    IoT & & & & & & & & & & &  \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

@leandriis 's answer is slicker by far, but since I've done it already here's my simple attempt. I recommend [Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/) for working things like this out.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{xs}} & \multirow{2}{*}{cs} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{sq} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{bo}} \\ \cline{6-9}
 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} &  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{po} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{ge} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} \\ \cline{2-12} 
 & SP & SI & SU & ant & not & store & nt & rtn & stp & inv & suc \\ \hline
Camera &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Camera &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
Cam &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
IoT &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of MWE output]

Comment: You should add `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}`in your preamble to add some padding at the top of rows,  in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I obtained:

```
\documentclass[
    10pt,%
    a4paper,%
    oneside,%
    ]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{comment}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\hspace{0pt}}p{1cm}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{My table.}

\begin{tabular}[t]{|p{2cm}|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|R|}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{}   & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow[t]{3}{*}{XSS}}  & \multirow[t]{2}{*}{CSRF} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{SQL injection} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{\multirow[t]{2}{*}{Buffer Overflow}}\\
\cline{6-9}
                    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{} & & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{POST} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{GET} &  \multicolumn{3}{c|}{}   \\
\cline{2-12}
                    & Store Payloads    & Sanitize (invalid)    & \textcolor{red}{Successful}   & \textcolor{red}{Anti-CSRf token}  & NOT   & \textcolor{red}{Store Payloads}   & NOT   & \textcolor{red}{Return Data}  & Store Payloads    & Invalid to store  & \textcolor{red}{Successful}\\
\hline
Camera2             &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
\hline
Camera1             &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
\hline
Cam                 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
\hline
IoT                 &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]